# "Project must be an Adobe AIR desktop project"?

Tags: flash, air, flash-builder

I am trying to get the workflow going between Flash Pro CS6 and Flash Builder 4.6, specifically being able to use Flash Builder to debug and publish an imported Flash Professional project as a desktop app. I've been stuck on this for days so any help appreciated.

My environment:

OSX 10.9.3

AIR 15/Flash Player 15 - sdks installed in both Flash Builder and Flash Pro

The steps I've followed for a test project:

1. Create a barebones project in Flash Pro. Specified settings for AIR extended desktop. Published it to get the .swf and project description generated.
2. Created a new project in Flash Builder, selecting my test .fla as root file. Project imports successfully and I am able to edit code and use Flash Builder to trigger a Flash Pro run or debug session.
3. Finally, I try to create a configuration profile in Flash Builder so I can run and debug it from there. Although it seems to see the files, I get an error that "Project must be an Adobe AIR desktop project." and other errors about requiring an application descriptor XML. That XML (generated by Flash) is sitting right next to the .swf in the bin-debug folder.

Any tips or things to try? There is almost nothing on the web about this. - Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this:

There is an option in Flash Builder to convert from a Web Project to a Desktop Project

1. Cmd/Control-click on the project name in the sidebar to display the context menu and select "Add/Change Project Type" and select "Convert..." etc.

[image]

---

2. This brings up another window with a few options in it

[image]